# jOOQ enum forcedType with annotation

Tags: kotlin, jooq

Currently I define the enum forcedType in gradle jooq configuration, but I would like to make it automatically set by annotation.

```
jooq {
  version.set(Versions.jooq)
  edition.set(OSS)

  configurations {
    create("main") {
      jooqConfiguration.apply {
        logging = Logging.INFO
        generator.apply {
          name = "org.jooq.codegen.KotlinGenerator"
          database.apply {
            name = "com.example.generator.StandalonePostgreSQLDatabase"
            inputSchema = "public"
            excludes = "flyway_schema_history"
            forcedTypes.addAll(
              listOf(
                ForcedType().apply {
                  isEnumConverter = true
                  includeTypes = "day_of_week"
                  userType = "com.example.api.enums.DayOfWeek"
                }
              )
            )
          }
          generate.apply {
            isDeprecated = false
            isRecords = true
            isImmutablePojos = true
            isFluentSetters = true
          }
          target.apply {
            packageName = "com.example.api"
            directory = "build/generated/jooq"
          }
          strategy.name = "com.example.common.JPrefixGeneratorStrategy"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When the enum class is annotated by @DatabaseEnum, I would like to add them as forcedType. Is there any possible way to do it?

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class DatabaseEnum(val includeType: String)

@DatabaseEnum(includeType = "day_of_week")
enum class DayOfWeek {
  MONDAY,
  TUESDAY,
  WEDNESDAY,
  THURSDAY,
  FRIDAY,
  SATURDAY,
  SUNDAY
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pending feature request for precisely this:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13167

As of jOOQ 3.18 (and probably 3.19) this isn't available out of the box yet.

You can obviously implement it yourself. For this to work you need:

- To scan your classpath while generating code (i.e. the annotated types need to be pre-compiled)
- Use [programmatic code generation configuration](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-programmatic/) of some sort, or implement your own gradle plugin.

Comment: That's great to hear that it is already in the pipeline :) many thx!